# UART TTL - Which pin is 5V?

Tags: uart, ttl, pinout

I have a board with the following connections:

TMS TDI TDO RXD TXD RTCK TRST TCK GND

I am trying to connect my USB UART TTL to it (I have connected the RXD, TXD, GND) but I am not sure which pin I should connect the 5v to?

Any advice would be great, thanks

Comment: Isn't there a VCC pin? What type of board do you have, could you please provide a part-number or datasheet?

Comment: I don't think it's any of those.  I think that there are other pins that you're missing.

Comment: The board should power itself from USB and probably provides 5 volts out on that pin, which your target board doesn't need. Try it with just the 3 connected.

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed in the comments, the USB-to-UART board is self-powered from USB and can **provide** +5V to the connected device. Since your connected device is also self-powered, the 5V pin should not be connected.